# Java calendar not clearing the hour of day

Tags: java, calendar

I am trying to clear the `HOUR_OF_DAY` from the Calendar in Java. For every other field, the value is getting cleared. Only for `HOUR_OF_DAY` it is not.

```
Calendar c = Calendar.getInstance();
c.clear(Calendar.MINUTE);
c.clear(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY);
System.out.println(c.getTime());
```

prints `Wed May 04 12:00:31 IST 2016`

at `2 PM` it prints `Wed May 04 14:00:31 IST 2016`

Comment: I dont feel like duplicating the question since there it does not specify the API doc (the reason behind why it doesnt work) @piyushjaiswal

Comment: For a date-only value, without time-of-day, use [`java.time.LocalDate`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/LocalDate.html).

Answer (score 6):

From [API of `clear`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Calendar.html#clear-int-):

> The `HOUR_OF_DAY`, `HOUR` and `AM_PM` fields are handled independently and the the resolution rule for the time of day is applied. Clearing one of the fields doesn't reset the hour of day value of this Calendar. Use `set(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY, 0)` to reset the hour value.

So,

```
c.set(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY, 0);
```

should get what you want.

Comment: clear() should throw a RuntimeException if the the api is used incorrectly, no? This is a real gotcha.